# Regex: Change all words before a certain one into uppercase

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I'm looking to take a string of the form:

Article Title Of Unknown Length by Author Name: some.url

And simply change it to:

ARTICLE TITLE OF UNKNOWN LENGTH by Author Name: some.url

I have tried various options that will successfully pick out the article title, such as

```
(^.*?by)
```

and will replace it with whatever I want. e.g. if I say

```
replace [(^.*?by)] with [test title]
```

the above becomes:

test title by Author Name: some.url

However, whenever I try to replace it with \U$1 it makes the whole string uppercase rather than just what matches the query.

What am I doing wrong? I am complete regex noob by the way, only started an hour ago, but any help would be hugely appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'Article Title Of Unknown Length by Author Name: some.url';
$string =~ s/^(.*)(?= by )/\U\1\E/gi;
print $string; # ARTICLE TITLE OF UNKNOWN LENGTH by Author Name: some.url
```

EDIT>

```
/           search for
^           at start of string 
(.*)        match and capture a group of 0+(`*`) any character (`.`)
(?= by )    followed by literal " by " (`?=` is positive lookahead)
/           replace with
\U          start upper-casing
\1          the first captured group
\E          stop upper-casing
/           options
g           search globally
i           case insensitive
```

Comment: Could you break that down a little for me? Sorry, I'm not a total code-phobe but I can't really follow what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Note how guido included spaces around that "by" for this regex to work with things like "Messing With Abby by Abby: some.url". You may want to replace them with "\s"s if there are tabs and such to be found in your input. Not sure how yahoo-pipes work. Most likely `replace [^(.*)(?= by )] with [\U$1]` will do the trick. Anyway, the pattern `^(.*)( by )(.*)$` will match the whole input, broken into three parts, so it should be easy from here to figure out how to reconstruct what you need like `replace [^(.*)( by )(.*)$] with [\U$1 by \$3]` or some such.

Comment: This sort of works, the problem I have is when I break into those 3 bits, and then ask it to replace the string with $1$2$3 reconstructs it fine.

If I then get it to do $1$2\\U$3 it gives me everything after the 'by' in caps, but if I do \\U$1$2$3 it gives me the whole thing in caps.

I'm sure Guido's answer is great, but for a complete novice like me it's too hard for me decode without a quick breakdown.

Comment: guido's solution is written for perl, not yahoo-pipes, but includes the regex shat should work. It should translate to yahoo-pipes like `replace [^(.*)(?= by )] with [\\U$1]`. This matches (and therefore replaces) only part of the string and, if yahoo-pipes support positive lookahead, should work.